# trouble installing dlib with pip

Tags: installation, pip, dlib

I tried downloading dlib with pip and here's what I got instead:

```
Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error


> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: 'c:\program
> files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,
> tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\\Users\\kiddr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dc0zubd\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kiddr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dc0zubd\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-f242luxg'
>        cwd: C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dc0zubd\dlib\  
> Complete output (53 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build  
> running build_py   package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py'
> not found (or not a regular file)   running build_ext   Traceback
> (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dc0zubd\dlib\setup.py",
> line 120, in get_cmake_version
>       out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
>       return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
>       self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
>       hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dc0zubd\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dc0zubd\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
      cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
    File "C:\Users\kiddr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dc0zubd\dlib\setup.py", line 122, in get_cmake_version
      raise RuntimeError("\n*******************************************************************\n" +
  RuntimeError:
  *******************************************************************
   CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: _dlib_pybind11
  *******************************************************************

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
```

Which is weird, because I did install CMake and even restarted my pc. I also added the path to site-packages into my PATH environment. I also already made sure that the pip was upgraded to the latest version, and tried manually downloading the zip version from github and installing it by unpacking the file and running setup.py as administrator. I ran into the exact same error code though.

Can anyone help please? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1.use python 3.6.9 version

2.first install cmake.

```
conda install -c anaconda cmake
```

use these command to install dlib

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```